# python get_document signature

Tags: python, docusignapi

What is the python signature for get_document()?

I'm getting the exception below when I call it like this (which is the C# signature):

```
docstream = envelopes_api.get_document(account_id, envelope_id, document_id)

docusign_esign.rest.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '159', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '961f6b00-3a25-4d47-895d-987ebe85a1f5', 'Date': 'Wed, 15 Aug 2018 13:29:31 GMT', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'})
HTTP response body: b'{\r\n  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",\r\n  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid value specified for envelopeId."\r\n}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I tried

```
docstream = envelopes_api.get_document(account_id, envelope_id, document_id)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the accepted answer is not correct in 2023. The call should be:

```
envelopes_api.get_document(account_id, document_id, envelope_id)
```